# Query to list data based comparison of 2 x numeric values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 query:

```
select 
    comp_companyid, balt, clim 
from 
    vCompanyOverCL
```

which returns multiple rows which each row as follows.

```
comp_companyid  balt  clim
--------------  ----  ----
          1112  1100  1000
```

I need to add a where clause that only returns data where the balt is 20% greater than clim (these are both numeric fields)

In the above example it wouldn't be returned as its only 10%

Any help would be appreciated.

Mim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use basic arithmetic operators in SQL Server so;

```
select comp_companyid, bald, clim from vCompanyOverCL
where balt * 100 >= clim * 120
```

Will basically do what you want. Not sure what kind of floating point errors you may get as I don't really know much about what SQL Server uses to rep floats. If it's IEEE then you should instead do; `where balt * 100 >= clim * 120` to avoid an int to float conversion.

EDIT: I changed the main code snippet because you **should not** allow either value to be cast to a float. It will cause floating point errors.

Comment: Perfect.. Thank you very much. I was making it sound more complicated that it needed to be

Comment: @Mim np. Please observe the edit. Not a good idea to use floats here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT comp_companyid, balt, clim
FROM vCompanyOverCL
WHERE balt > 1.2 * clim
```